# Can we regard file-system structure as one part of architecture?

Tags: architecture, file-structure

Put this image inside `images` folder. All JavaScript files should go inside a folder called `js`. Put templates inside a folder called site-templates and for each template, have three folders called `layouts`, `looks`, and `pages`.

We're all familiar with these file-system structures in which we try to logically and efficiently categorize files and folders in an acceptable hierarchy inside our projects. On the other hand, because many times we do I/O operations on these files, changing the file-system structure forces us to update parts of our code, no matter how high-tech, and decoupled our code is.

My question is, based on the effect that a file-system structure has on an overall project, can we consider it as a part of the software architecture? Because, in many cases, choosing a correct file-system structure prevents us from duplicating a file, say jQuery, in many places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure we can, we even must sometimes. I've seen several projects which subdivided their file storages into several folders solely for performance purposes — this is quite the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If the file system layout is known to all parts of the application then it is not decoupled enough, and you should reconsider how to centralize this knowledge.

Comment: Then what is the answer to the question? Is file-system structure an architecture?